# Batch not echoing single digit to file

Tags: batch-file, echo

In part of my code, I am trying to echo a single number to a file:

```
echo 1>test.txt
```

Except the command interpreter does not pick up the single digit, echoing

```
Echo is off.
```

to the file.  Is there any way to work around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the easiest solution

```
>test.txt echo 1
```

Why does it solve the problem? What the problem is?

In batch files, input and output streams are numbered from 0 to 9: `0= stdin = default input stream`, `1= stdout = default output stream`, `2= stderr = default error stream` and 3 to 9 available to the user.

The problem with your code is that the expression `1> file` means `redirect the stream 1 (standard output) to the file`. The parser handles the digit as part of the redirection, not as data to send to the redirection.

To solve the problem it is necessary to separate the digit from the redirection operator, but something as `echo 1 >test.txt` will also output an aditional space, usually an undesired behaviour.

Changing how the command is written by reordering the line we can separate the digit and the redirection without any aditional element.

*edited to adapt to comments*

Can it be done without reordering?

Yes, you can also separate the command from the redirection operator enclosing the command in parenthesis

```
(echo 1)>test.txt
```

or you can add aditional indications to the parser, escaping the digit

```
echo ^1>test.txt
```

or use a `for` replaceable parameter to handle the digit, hiding it to the parser at redirection time

```
for %%a in (1) do echo %%a>test.txt
```

or, use delayed expansion, or .... virtually anything that ensures that the parser does not handle the digit as a stream number.

Comment: or `(echo( 1)>test.txt`

Comment: @npocmaka, yes, or `echo ^1>test.txt`, but the reason is the same and depending on where the code is placed both the closing parenthesis or the caret can interfere. Changing the order in the line is easier.

Comment: or `echo ^1>test.txt`

Comment: @npocmaka: Your example store `" 1"` (space-one) in the file. It should be `(echo(1)>test.txt` instead, or simpler yet: `(echo 1)>test.txt`